# Jquery stopPropagation not working, two cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

```js
$(document).on('click', '.outer1', function(){
    alert('outer click event');
})

$(document).on('click', '.inner1', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('inner click event');
})

$('.outer2').on('click', function(){
    alert('outer click event');
})

$(document).on('click', '.inner2', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('inner click event');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer1">
   <div class="inner1"> Case 1 - Click Here</div>
</div>


<div class="outer2">
   <div class="inner2"> Case 2 - Click Here</div>
</div>
```

For example, modal window:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

First case:

```
$(document).on('click', '.outer', function(){
    alert('outer click event');
})

$(document).on('click', '.inner', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('inner click event');
})
```

Second case:

```
$('.outer').on('click', function(){
    alert('outer click event');
})

$(document).on('click', '.inner', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('inner click event');
})
```

What is the difference? Why stopPropagation() working in first case, but not working in second case?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan had given correct answer. If you want to use Second Case then you have to use `$('.inner').on('click', function(e){` instead of `$(document).on('click', '.inner', function(e){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter doesn't work because the event needs to bubble up through the DOM from `.inner` to `document` for it to be caught by the delegated event handler.

However, it's caught by the event handler on `.outer` as it bubbles up and this is *before* the `stopPropagation()` call has been made.

Comment: In other words, that second parameter is only a filter for events as they bubble up, not an element that has a listener attached.